# It depends on the rule(s) you "broke" vs. "are breaking"

Tags: tense

I guy just joined a company, he asks one of his colleges:

> Question: "Is our boss lenient or strict?"
>
> Answer: "It depends on the rule(s) **you broke**. If you're just being late at work, it doesn't matter at all. If you fail the contract with our VIP, you better find a new job."

Should I use "are breaking" or "broke" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just say "It depends on the rule(s) you **break**".  From the context, it sounds like the colleague is asking about the boss in general, rather than about a specific situation.  I would not use the past tense here unless a you are talking about a specific example of rule-breaking.  For example, suppose the colleague asked:

"I think I did something wrong yesterday.  Is our boss lenient or strict".

Then I might respond with:

"It depends on the rule you broke..."

because you are discussing a specific instance of rule-breaking that occurred in the past.